# Define a new evironment by an existed environment, with its optional argument

Tags: environments

Suppose there is an existed environment say, `existedenv`, with an optional argument, that is,

```
\begin{existedenv}[argument]
....
\end{existedenv}
```

I want to define a new environment, say, `myenv`, which is a copy of `existedenv`, that is,

```
\begin{myenv}[argument]
....
\end{myenv}
```

behavior is exactly like

```
\begin{existedenv}[argument]
....
\end{existedenv}
```

How to write the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just define `myenv` like this:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
    % maybe some code here
    \begin{existedenv}%
    % but no code here!
}{%
    \end{existedenv}%
}
```

The when you write `\begin{myenv}[argument]` the `\begin{myenv}` is expanded to `\begin{existedenv}` and it results in `\begin{existedenv}[argument]`.
This isn't an option if you need code after the `\begin{existedenv}` and won't work without modification when `existedenv` is a verbatim or pseudo-environment (i.e. reads its body as argument like `beamer`s `frame`).

Comment: That's definitely good to know! Do macros inherit options, too?

Comment: @Raphink: It works with macros as well. However I wouldn't call it 'inherit options'. It's all about expansion.

Comment: @Raphink: This technique is more like "partial application" or "currying/uncurrying" in functional languages.

Answer (score 9):

If you really, really don't need any extra functionality, you can cheat a little:

```
\let\myenv\existedenv
\let\endmyenv\endexistedenv
```

Otherwise, i.e. if you want to inspect all the arguments for some reason, things get more complicated because there are environments with multiple optargs (e.g. `minipage`), args in parentheses (`picture`), optional args in curly braces (beamer's `frame`) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The code would be:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}[#args] {%
    %code coult be put here
    \begin{existedenv}{#1}..{#args}%
    %code could be put here but must be valid inside existedenv
}{%
    \end{existedenv}%
}
```

Where #args is the number of args used by existedenv.

Comment: I don't understand the `..[#args]` part. You might mean: `{#2}..{#args}`. Also you need to place `%` after the two `{` and after `\end{existedenv}`
 to avoid unwanted spaces.

Comment: Yes I meant {#1}..{#args} if #args>0 and if #args == 0, leave it empty. I fix(ed) it in the answer above. I added the %.

Comment: The `#1` is the optional one, so you need to write `[#1]{#2}..{#args}` (for #args > 2 of course).

Comment: Anyway you could also write {#1}{#2} as {#1} must not be optional, or am I wrong here? I think if you need {} or [] depends on the environment used.

Comment: Sure, that's true. The OP just requested an optional argument, so I thought your answer is specific to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do anything to the optional argument of `myenv` you can write it without the argument and let `existingenv` take care of it:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{
  % stuff of your own...
  \existingenv
}{
  \endexistingenv
}
```

Then `\begin{myenv}[foo]` will expand to `\begin{existingenv}[foo]` before `foo` is expanded.

But if this is all you want to do you might consider using some the macros in the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to just patch the environment.  For instance,

```
\pretocmd{\A}{stuff of your own}{}{}
```

will just insert the code you want before the begin-code of `A`.